# How to add honeypot to forms in TYPO3 Version 11?

Tags: typo3-11.x, typo3-form

There use to be an extension for honeypot in TYPO3. My understanding is that in the newer versions of TYPO3 (version 11 and latest, there is no separate extension required and a honeypot field is included in the system form extension. Is that true?

If yes, how can i see and use it in my form? Below is the image of form elements that i currently see. My TYPO3 version is 11.5.16

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, the honeypot field is integrated into the form by default.
The [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Config/proto/formElements/formElementTypes/Form.html#renderingoptions-honeypot-enable) says that the honeypot field cannot be activated via form editor.

Anyway, the honeypot field is automatically present in the HTML in my contact form.
However, it seems that either the spammers are tricking the field or the finisher is not blocking the sending.
Anyway, I get spam every day through my contact form.
An explanation would be appreciated by me as well.

Comment: I am new to TYPO3 and have only used it as an editor so far. Could you kindly tell me how to enable the field. Do i have to make changes in my_form_definition.yaml file?

Comment: You don't have to do anything, the honeypot field is enabled by default.
In the form you have a field similar the following by default.  

`<input autocomplete="VmRKfFYSosyu7" aria-hidden="true" id="test-296-VmRKfFYSosyu7" style="position:absolute; margin:0 0 0 -999em;" tabindex="-1" type="text" name="tx_form_formframework[test-296][VmRKfFYSosyu7]">`  

  
If the form is filled by a robot, so the data won't be sent.

Comment: Did you try derhansen/form_crshield, I wonder how good it works? Or did you implement other measures?

Comment: I used the TYPO3 sysext Package typo3/cms-form.
In other projects i used derhansen/form_crshield as well. This also works very well